# Synaptics driver not loaded

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics

synclient says `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`. Is there any fix?

I have a Lenovo X250 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 but with kernel 4.4.0-040400-generic (I had to upgrade it to get wifi working properly). This is my hardware:

```
$ xinput; dmesg | grep pnp
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2+USB Mouse                            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 046a:0011                             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.359545] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.361034] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.361088] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs LEN0071 PNP0303 (active)
[    0.361140] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs LEN0046 PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.361676] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs SMO1200 PNP0c31 (active)
[    0.362359] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 7 devices
[    1.227586] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed15fff], which spans more than pnp 00:01 [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed13fff]
```

I tried `sudo rmmod psmouse` and `sudo modprobe -v psmouse` suggested on another thread, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this script. This will enable your touchpad if it was disabled by any chance

```
gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```

If it doesn't help out , try turning on individual settings :

```
sudo trackpad show
sudo trackpad tap
sudo trackpad drag
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The script didn't change anything, and I couldn't find the "trackpad" command ("locate trackpad" doesn't give anything).

Comment: BTW, I had a chance to try a different laptop (by physically swapping the disk), and "synclient" didn't work there either. So I guess it's not a hardware problem.